# Binary Search Tree toString Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, tostring

I've implemented `toString` method for BST, but looks like it works but is not stable.
for example
for this tree `toString` works fine:
[image: correct]
but for this one, it's wrong
[image: wrong]

Can anyone help, what's going on?

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + toStringB(new StringBuilder(), root()).toString() + ")";
    }

    private StringBuilder toStringB(StringBuilder string, Node<E> node) {
        if (node != null) {
            string.append(node.getElement());
            if (left(node) != null) {
                toStringB(string.append(" ("), left(node));
            }
            if (right(node) != null) {
                toStringB(string.append(", "), right(node));
                string.append(')');
            }
        }
        return string;
    }
```

Comment: Could you give us the full code so we can run it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
        if (left(node) != null) {
            toStringB(string.append(" ("), left(node));
        }
        if (right(node) != null) {
            toStringB(string.append(", "), right(node));
            string.append(')');
        }
```

If you have a left node, but no right node, you will append `(left`.  If you have a right node with no left node, you will append `, right)`.   This gives you your improperly matched parentheses, and stray commas.

I'd like to point out, your "works fine" example actually is not correct, either:

> (10 (7 (3 (2, 5), 9), 10, 30 (11 (10)))

Let's hide the nodes under 7 and 30:

> (10 (7 (...), 10, 30 (...))

Your root node `10` has 3 children `7`, `10`, and `30`.  This is not a binary tree!

Oh, and unbalanced parentheses, as well.

Comment: oh, thanks, didn't noticed this. can you help to fix it please?

Comment: If you have a left node OR a right node, append the open parentheses.  If you have a left node, append it.  If you have a left AND right node, append a comma.  If you have a right node, append it.  If you have a left OR right node, append a close parenthesis.

Comment: oh, thank you so much, for now it works! (10(5(3(2),9),10(30(11(10)))))